# change html code of rooms in HTML 5 client of bigbluebutton source?

Tags: html, css, bigbluebutton

how can I change **html** code of rooms in BigBlueButton source code??and how can I change Css of elements in room sessions? for example i want to set 'display:none' for logo of bigbluebutton in room.

Comment: Add more details, some code samples would help here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `style="display:none;"` in the  tag of the concerned logo.
it would look like:
`<img src="the_logo_path" style="display:none;">`

or you can put an id on that  tag in html file and then in CSS stylesheet you can add `display:none;` property.
e.g.
in HTML file `<img id="bbb_logo" src="xxxxxxx">`
in Stylesheet: `#bbb_logo { display: none;}`

Comment: I know that  . but I can't find the source in my server

Comment: Open the rooms and find the respective id or class via DevOps Tools provided by the browser (Ctrl+I), when you get it you can add it at the end of the stylesheet.